# Erro na linha 0 (zero)? Como pode isso?

Tags: php

No PHP, quando ocorre um erro, geralmente a linha do script onde ocorreu o mesmo é informada:

> Undefined index 'a' in line 5

Porém há momentos em que é retornado erro na linha 0 (zero).

Exemplo:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function items() on a non-object in File.php on line 0

Pelo tempo que trabalho com PHP, sei muito bem que a contagem de linhas do script começa a partir do `1` e não do `0`

Exemplo:

```
 <?= __LINE__ ?> // Retorna 1
```

Qual é o motivo de o PHP as vezes retornar `Erro in Line 0`? É algum bug? Ou isso tem explicação lógica?

Comment: Ola amigo, por favor seria mais fácil te ajudar se você colocar seus códigos para podermos ver aonde possivelmente esta o erro.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no segundo exemplo

Comment: Não quero saber de um erro específico. Na verdade eu quero saber **onde fica essa tal de linha 0**.

Comment: Converter erros em exceções pode ajudar (peguei [daqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564103/error-pointing-to-line-0-in-php)). Minha experiência com linguagens de script é que as vezes o motor dá um erro em alguma coisa que você está puxando de outro arquivo, e aí ele não consegue obter a referência ao ponto exato onde o erro ocorreu e indica linha zero. Não sei se o PHP pré-compila mais se fizer isso é mais um indício de que pode ser algo do tipo.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo, poderia pelo menos fazer a gentileza de deixar um feedback aí, pra ver o que pode ser arrumado na pergunta.

Comment: Normalmente quando faz uso de `call_user_function()`, `eval()`, `overload`, e coisas do tipo que tornam o fluxo do código obscuro. O interpretador não consegue obter a linha de onde originou-se a interrupção ou o notice error. Mas não posso afirmar que seja isso para o seu caso específico. E claro, não estou dizendo que é ruim usar as funções mencionadas. Tente dar um `debug_backtrace()` e vai na raça mesmo enfiando breakpoints pelos códigos. E compartilha conosco o que encontrou heheh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dando uma olhada nos fontes do interpretador PHP, cheguei a algumas conclusões.

O interpretador PHP lida com vários tipos de erro (exceções, warnings, avisos de deprecated, etc.). O comportamento padrão para a maioria dos casos é mostrar uma  mensagem conforme abaixo:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s in %s on line %u\n", error_type_str, buffer, error_filename, error_lineno);
```

(Esse trecho foi retirado da função `php_error_cb` do arquivo main.c do interpretador)

O último parâmetro, `error_lineno`, é o mais relevante neste caso porque indica a linha do erro.

De onde vem este valor? Sem entrar em muitos detalhes, o interpretador busca a linha do contexto de execução do programa, basicamente o que o PHP estava executando no momento do erro.

Existem no entanto situações específicas que não é possível obter este valor. E portanto é usado um valor default, 0, que resulta na mensagem que você descreveu.

Em suma, a linha "0" não é literalmente uma linha, é um valor padrão usado pelo PHP quando ele não "sabe" qual é a linha.

Answer (score 0):

o seu erro é mais ou menos esse:

*Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **Unknown on line 0**
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/revisãomudanca.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0*

Então, isso ocorreu comigo também, ai verifiquei **a action**, onde o dados estavam indo:

Pode ser que esse seja seu erro, o nome da **action** deve ser o mesmo nome do arquivo em php que será lançado os dados.

Uma outra possiblidade é que você tenha salvado o arquivo com algum caractere invalidade, como ç ou ~~, ou qualquer outro acento, salve o nome do arquivo sem nemhum acento.

Answer (score -4):

Já aconteceu comigo algo parecido, veja se na primeira linha aonde você abre a tag do PHP não tem nenhum espaço:

```
espaço aqui<?php ?>

<?php ?> <-- deve ficar assim
```