# Erro: "Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"

Tags: php

Boa tarde! Estou desenvolvendo um site o registro de um site em PHP, e quando eu clico para cadastrar, eu recebo esse erro:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www/Feira_de_Ciências/php/inserir.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0"

O que posso fazer?
O meu PHP está bem simples

HTML

Bem vindo
  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

```
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Registro</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">  
      <h1>Registre-se</h1>

      <form action="inserir.php" method="post">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Nome<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="rnome" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" name="remail" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Senha<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required name ="rsenha" autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Registrar</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="login">  
      <h1>Bem vindo de volta!</h1>

      <form action="/" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required name="lemail" autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Senha<span class="req" >*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required name="lsenha" autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>



      <button class="button button-block"/>Logar</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div><!-- tab-content -->
```

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>

```
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

PHP

> echo "teste";

No Pastebin
PHP: https://pastebin.com/z8TqTX1k
Index: https://pastebin.com/1PHTJuTa

Comment: olá, inclua o código da página na pergunta para facilitar a leitura. Algumas pessoas podem também não ter acesso a outros locais fora do SOpt

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128124/erro-na-linha-0-zero-como-pode-isso

Comment: Certo, só um momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente 2 coisas são possiveis:

1. O acento no `ê` em `Feira_de_Ciências`
2. Você esta escrevendo coisas dentro de uma pasta que requer privilégio de administrador `Programs and Files (x86)`

Comment: e tem as maiusculas e minusculas pra atrapalhar mais ainda na se for upar pra linux depois

Comment: obrigado! Era isso mesmo!